# Allow PHP codes in Wordpress posts & pages (Using functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to write pure PHP codes in WP posts - not using a plugin or snippets etc.

I know this Q has been asked before, but all were answered by using plugins etc.
There were some plugins like PHP-Exec that could do the job, but due to latest WP/PHP updates they no longer work.

Is there any way to write some functions in FUNCTIONS.PHP to allow this?
So a code like this can work as a WP post?

```
<p>
My text paragraph.
</p>

<?php
// Custom PHP codes - vary in wp posts
echo "Anything ... ";
?>

<p>
My second text paragraphs.
</p>
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to wrap your PHP code in a shortcode inside `functions.php` and then call it out of your page.

```
function anything_function() { 
  
// your actual functionality.
$message = "Anything ... "; 
  
return $message;
}
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('anything', 'anything_function');
```

And then you can use the `[anything]` shortcode inside your templates.
Please refer to [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something that would allow inline codes rather than calling functions, because I have over 100 posts with totally custom inline codes, some even calling (require_once) php files etc.

Something exactly like Exec-PHP plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/ 

Is this possible?